# How to pick a particular return type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, union-types

Lets say return type of a  function is `a | b`. Now if I know that the return type will be `a` for sure for a particular call, how do I tell typescript to treat the returned value as `a`. Normally if I try this:

```
const x: a = func();
```

I get `type a | b is not assignable to type a`

Comment: As in `func` normally returns `a | b` and you want to say that in *this* case, you're certain it'd be only `a` or you want to make `func` only return `a`?

Comment: only in _this_ case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting the particular value you're interested in is certainly a valid option, but it's based on a hidden assumption that only you, the programmer, know about. If 6 months down the line you change the behaviour of your function in such a way that your assumption is no longer valid, you'll get a runtime error.

A more robust solution would be to encode your assumption in the program through the type system, either via overloading or via conditional types.

For example:

```
function f1(x: string): number | string {
    return undefined;
}

const a1: number = f1('foo') // wrong, can't do

function f2(x: string): string
function f2(): number
function f2(x?: string): number | string {
    return undefined;
}

const a2s: string = f2('foo') // OK
const a2n: number = f2() // OK
```

Similarly, conditional types allow you to express the same thing:

```
function f3<T>(x?: T): T extends string ? string : number {
    return undefined;
}

const a3s: string = f3('foo') // OK
const a3n: number = f3()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false&ssl=21&ssc=25&pln=16&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAjACgB4C5EGcoBOMYA5gJQ5ggC2ARgKYGIA+ehxJiA3gFCL+IC9KCAJJwAE3rBi9CQG4eAXx48ICfIgCGKSjQZMAvMnQByYHDimyiAPS3EAdwIISAGkQQtYU1EQS4VVBIWARkACZMHHwiUgo2WJIeYOh4JGBI+Ko6RmTwVLCMzAB+aPY4vRymVhiObj4BIRExRElpWQVlVXUwTS1w3DLExGMi80trOwcAeQBpNQ0-frBKgxGItBt7RDmg-ND0gGYAHgAVAD4SnFP408R6DCh6MAlcBLri99JEVcZ6gUEwlE4he7TAckUKgWvSWh0GX04o0OaHGVi2M3mPT6hxWiGyayRmyAA)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the function is coming from a library and it is a method of an object. How can I make it work in that case?

Comment: Is it a plain JS function? If that's the case, you can write a type definition for it in a `d.ts` file. Another option is to write a wrapper around that function, so that you have full control over it

Answer (score 3):

Just cast the return type:

```
const x = <a>func();
```

OR

```
const x = func() as a;
```

In this way, you are telling typescript that you know for sure what the return type is.

---

Another way to do it is to create an overload for the function like so:

```
function func(): a;
```

Then call it like you did originally

```
const x: a = func();
```